# PThreads and Malloc causing inaccessible memory

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, malloc

I have a hash table which utilizes threads to insert elements. Each hash bucket is mutex locked for a thread to add/traverse the hash chain inside that bucket. Each time an insert_word function is called, the function generates a thread, and returns. The thread is then in charge of searching for a place to put the data and allocating the memory if necessary.

The purpose of the table is to count the occurances of a word inside a text document. The implementation works for small file sizes (~5kb), but when testing with a larger file (25kb), the program segfaults.

Using GDB, it shows that the program segfaults at the following line:

```
if(!strcmp(next->word, word))
```

Printing next shows that it has an address (sometimes 0x20, sometimes 0x530000007365, sometimes 0x64, sometimes 0x74656e), and GDB says that next->word cannot be accessed.

This location should have been malloced at:;

```
next = (struct hashEntry *)malloc(sizeof(struct hashEntry));
curr->next = next;
next->word = strdup(word);
next->count = 1;
```

It appears that the memory has been allocated and data is accessed and utilized at that address, so why would it suddenly be inaccessible?

EDIT: Should specify the contents of the struct

```
struct hashEntry {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct hashEntry *next;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialise `next->next`, so the last element of the linked list contains some random value in `next`. You should implicitly set it to `NULL` and check for `curr->next` being `NULL` to detect the end of the linked list.

Comment: Wow, that was the simplest fix ever that I spent 2 hours debugging. THANKS!

Comment: @isedev: Why not make this an answer?